# Jotai with IndexedDB get and set value dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite, indexeddb, jotai

I have created this custom atom that uses the idb-keyval library to get and set values from indexeddb:

```
export function atomWithAsyncStorage<T>(key: string, initial?: T) {
  const store = createStore("conexsys-db", "keyval-store");

  return atomWithStorage<T>(key, initial, {
    setItem: (key, newValue) => set(key, newValue, store),
    getItem: (key) =>
      get<T>(key, store).then((value) => {
        if (value !== undefined) {
          return value;
        }
        if (initial !== undefined) {
          set(key, initial, store);
        }
        return initial;
      }),
    removeItem: (key) => del(key),
  });
}
```

This atom can then be created this way:

```
export const contextsAtom = atomWithAsyncStorage("CONTEXTS", []);

const [contexts, setContexts] = useAtom(contextsAtom);
```

The thing about the above atom is it uses the "CONTEXTS" value in the indexedDB store, but how can I dynamically from my react component set any value to indexedDB using Jotai too?

For example, if I have a URL id, how can I do something like:

```
  const [contexts, setContexts] = useAtom(contextsAtom, "usethisid"); OR
  const [contexts, setContexts] = useAtom(contextsAtom("usethisid"));
```